# How to handle static content in OrbeonForms 3.9

Tags: orbeon

I trying to upgrade from OrbeonForms version 3.8 to 3.9. I'm using `PriorityResourceManagerFactory` as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.factory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.orbeon.oxf.resources.PriorityResourceManagerFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Uncomment this for the filesystem resource manager -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.priority.1</param-name>
    <param-value>org.orbeon.oxf.resources.FilesystemResourceManagerFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.priority.1.oxf.resources.filesystem.sandbox-directory</param-name>
    <param-value>d:/Sources/esb-repository/user-interface</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.priority.2</param-name>
    <param-value>org.orbeon.oxf.resources.WebAppResourceManagerFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.priority.2.oxf.resources.webapp.rootdir</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.priority.3</param-name>
    <param-value>org.orbeon.oxf.resources.FilesystemResourceManagerFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>oxf.resources.priority.3</param-name>
    <param-value>org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ClassLoaderResourceManagerFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have entry in page-flow.xml:

```
<files path-info=".+\.(gif|css|pdf|json|js|png|jpg|xsd|ico)"
    matcher="oxf:perl5-matcher"/>
```

Within my directory I keep whole application code and I have file *theme/styles/layout.css*. In Orbeon 3.8 server path `/orbeon/theme/styles/layout.css` works perfectly, but not in 3.9.

How to configure it to keep backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume `/orbeon` is the context on which you deployed the Orbeon Forms web app.

1. If you're using Orbeon Forms PE, starting with 3.9 versioned resources are [enabled by default](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/39#TOC-CSS-and-JavaScript-resources), the path requested by the browser needs to be `/orbeon/3.14/theme/styles/layout.css`, where `3.14` is the app version. If you write `/theme/styles/layout.css` in your code, Orbeon Forms will automatically rewrite it for you, adding the version number in the HTML it sends to the browser.
2. Since 3.9, the [default app path is prepended when looking up resources](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/39#TOC-Default-app-path-prepended-for-resources). So a request for `/orbeon/3.14/theme/styles/layout.css`, with versioned resources, or `/orbeon/theme/styles/layout.css` without versioned resources, will look for the file `app/theme/styles/layout.css` in your resource directory. So you need to either:

   - Move your CSS to a different place on disk (move `theme` under the `app` directory).
   - Add `theme` as a *platform path*, by adding it to the [`oxf.url-rewriting.platform-paths` property](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-base#TOC-oxf.url-rewriting.platform-paths). Most likely this is the option that makes the most sense for you.